# Beamer & reducing the size of citations

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, footnotes

How does it possible to decrease the size of the foot note citation in beamer in one page (locally)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%add  a sample .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibexample.bib}
 @article{sigfridsson,
  title = {Four-dimensional flow {MRI} using spiral acquisition},
  volume = {68},
  number = {4},
  journal = {Magnetic Resonance in Medicine},
  author = {Sigfridsson, Andreas and Petersson, Sven and Carlhäll, Carl-Johan 
  and Ebbers, Tino},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {1065--1073}
 }
\end{filecontents}

% ===================================================================
\usepackage[style=ieee,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibexample.bib}
%=============================================================

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{1}

    \begin{block}{definition}
        There is a special type of non-stationary stochastic 
 processes\footfullcite{sigfridsson} when their statistical properties vary 
periodically\footnote{element} with time called cyclostationary processes 
\footfullcite{sigfridsson}.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{1}

    \begin{block}{definition}
        There is a special type of non-stationary stochastic 
 processes\footfullcite{sigfridsson} when their statistical properties vary 
periodically\footnote{element} with time called cyclostationary processes 
\footfullcite{sigfridsson}.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are OK with also reducing the size of normal footnotes, this can easily be done via `\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%add  a sample .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibexample.bib}
 @article{sigfridsson,
  title = {Four-dimensional flow {MRI} using spiral acquisition},
  volume = {68},
  number = {4},
  journal = {Magnetic Resonance in Medicine},
  author = {Sigfridsson, Andreas and Petersson, Sven and Carlhäll, Carl-Johan 
  and Ebbers, Tino},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {1065--1073}
 }
\end{filecontents}

% ===================================================================
\usepackage[style=ieee,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibexample.bib}
%=============================================================

\usetheme{Frankfurt}



\begin{document}

{
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{1}

    \begin{block}{definition}
        There is a special type of non-stationary stochastic 
 processes\footfullcite{sigfridsson} when their statistical properties vary 
periodically\footnote{element} with time called cyclostationary processes 
\footfullcite{sigfridsson}.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mean it should be locally reduce the size for just one page not all the slides. This is because in one page I do not have enough space and I need to reduce the size of references in foot note.

Comment: @Amin See my updated code